# IE geJSON not encoding german character

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

when I try to send german character to the server, instad of correct I got some wird characters. I use mvc2 and jquery 1.8.1

I try to send this way

```
function changeFileName(value, selection, oppId, idForOkImg) {
            alert(value);
            $.getJSON('<%= Url.ActionOrm("ChangeTypeOfFile", "Opportunity")%>?fileName=' + value , null , function () {
                displayUploadedFiles(idForOkImg);

            });
        }
```

value which i pass is word "Prüfung"

and on the server side I recieve "Pr�fung", this problem exists on Internet explorer and Firefox, on chrom all is fine.

Comment: do you try utf8 en-/decode your value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode it like this:

```
$.getJSON('<%= Url.ActionOrm("ChangeTypeOfFile", "Opportunity")%>', 
{ fileName: encodeURIComponent(value) }, 
function () {
    displayUploadedFiles(idForOkImg);
});
```

In c#:

```
string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Request["fileName"]; //Pr%C3%BCfung
fileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileName); //Prüfung
```